# Weird lighting in rendered viewport shading

Tags: lighting

So I'm getting this weird colored lighting thing going on when I have the viewport shading set to rendered. I am very new to blender and am just barely doing the donut tutorial from blender guru, so I have no clue what is going on and not the slightest idea of how to fix it...

[image]

Comment: Without knowing anything else, I suspect a graphics driver issue. Try updating yours,

Comment: For clarification I am on a PC running Manjaro Linux. AMD APU with a AMD driver.